# Opentok library stopped working on S7 edge

Tags: android, java-native-interface, opentok

it was working prev but its crashing from today
Device

> Galaxy S7 Edge (hero2lte)
>
> Manufacturer Samsung Android version
>
> Android 6.0  RAM (MB) 4096  OpenGL ES  version 3.1 Native platform
>
> armeabi-v7a CPU make Samsung CPU model Exynos 8890

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.metronomic.materno-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.metronomic.materno-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.metronomic.materno-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libopentok.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
    at com.opentok.android.Session.<clinit>(Session.java:52)
    at com.metronomic.pregnancy.VideoConsultActivity.sessionConnect(VideoConsultActivity.java:506)
    at com.metronomic.pregnancy.VideoConsultActivity.onCreate(VideoConsultActivity.java:155)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution:
Add this to app level gradle .

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
    }
}
```

But i want to know in detail why and what is difference , after adding this code snippet .